# php mail() failing on localhost setup

Tags: php, email, sendmail.exe

My goal is to send an email (SMTP) to a local mail server using php.
I can't get it to work and I have little idea about what the problem is.

I have a setup (Vista laptop) consisting of WAMP, sendmail and hMailServer.

I'm trying to send an email to test@localhost.localdomain using the following simple php script.

```
<?php
$email = "test@localhost.localdomain";
$subject = "New User";
$message = "Hello User, Thank you for joining our website";
$message = wordwrap($message, 70);
$header = "MIME-Version: 1.0 Content-type: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1\n"; 
$header.= "From: Admin\n";
$status = mail($email,$subject,$message,$header);
?>
```

However, the mail() function fails and in the hMailServer log the error seems to be "The address is not valid."

```
"SMTPD" 6620    85  "2012-02-29 19:43:28.192"   "127.0.0.1" "SENT: 220 127.0.0.1 ESMTP"
"SMTPD" 7088    85  "2012-02-29 19:43:28.193"   "127.0.0.1" "RECEIVED: HELO ThomasPC"
"SMTPD" 7088    85  "2012-02-29 19:43:28.193"   "127.0.0.1" "SENT: 250 Hello."
"SMTPD" 5920    85  "2012-02-29 19:43:28.194"   "127.0.0.1" "RECEIVED: MAIL FROM:<you@yourdomain>"
"SMTPD" 5920    85  "2012-02-29 19:43:28.195"   "127.0.0.1" "SENT: 550 The address is not valid."
"SMTPD" 12756   85  "2012-02-29 19:43:28.195"   "127.0.0.1" "RECEIVED: QUIT"
"SMTPD" 12756   85  "2012-02-29 19:43:28.196"   "127.0.0.1" "SENT: 221 goodbye"
```

This is from php.ini

```
[mail function]
; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/smtp
;SMTP = localhost
; http://php.net/smtp-port
;smtp_port = 25

; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/sendmail-from
sendmail_from = wamp@localhost.localdomain

; For Unix only.  You may supply arguments as well (default: "sendmail -t -i").
; http://php.net/sendmail-path
sendmail_path = c:/sendmail/sendmail.exe -t

; Force the addition of the specified parameters to be passed as extra parameters
; to the sendmail binary. These parameters will always replace the value of
; the 5th parameter to mail(), even in safe mode.
;mail.force_extra_parameters =

; Add X-PHP-Originating-Script: that will include uid of the script followed by the filename
mail.add_x_header = On

; Log all mail() calls including the full path of the script, line #, to address and headers
;mail.log =
```

This is sendmail.ini

```
; configuration for fake sendmail

; if this file doesn't exist, sendmail.exe will look for the settings in
; the registry, under HKLM\Software\Sendmail

[sendmail]

; you must change mail.mydomain.com to your smtp server,
; or to IIS's "pickup" directory.  (generally C:\Inetpub\mailroot\Pickup)
; emails delivered via IIS's pickup directory cause sendmail to
; run quicker, but you won't get error messages back to the calling
; application.

; smtp_server=mail.mydomain.com
; Uncomment following to deliver emails directly into folder (create folder manually)
; smtp_server=c:\sendmail\log\
smtp_server=localhost.localdomain

; smtp port (normally 25)

smtp_port=25

; SMTPS (SSL) support
;   auto = use SSL for port 465, otherwise try to use TLS
;   ssl  = alway use SSL
;   tls  = always use TLS
;   none = never try to use SSL

smtp_ssl=auto

; the default domain for this server will be read from the registry
; this will be appended to email addresses when one isn't provided
; if you want to override the value in the registry, uncomment and modify

; set default domain
default_domain=localhost.localdomain

; log smtp errors to error.log (defaults to same directory as sendmail.exe)
; uncomment to enable logging
; ! create directory [c:\wamp\bin\sendmail\log] manually

error_logfile=error.log

; create debug log as debug.log (defaults to same directory as sendmail.exe)
; uncomment to enable debugging

debug_logfile=debug.log

; if your smtp server requires authentication, modify the following two lines

auth_username=test@localhost.localdomain
auth_password=blah

; if your smtp server uses pop3 before smtp authentication, modify the 
; following three lines.  do not enable unless it is required.

pop3_server=
pop3_username=
pop3_password=

; force the sender to always be the following email address
; this will only affect the "MAIL FROM" command, it won't modify 
; the "From: " header of the message content

force_sender=

; force the sender to always be the following email address
; this will only affect the "RCTP TO" command, it won't modify 
; the "To: " header of the message content

force_recipient=test@localhost.localdomain

; sendmail will use your hostname and your default_domain in the ehlo/helo
; smtp greeting.  you can manually set the ehlo/helo name if required

hostname=localhost.localdomain
```

hMailServer is set up with one domain: localhost.localdomain with two accounts test@localhost.localdomain and wamp@localhost.localdomain.

Can you see what might be wrong in this setup?

Best regards,
niarn

Comment: i think you need a qualified DNS-able domain to send mail to say google. I could be wrong though. Is it hitting your spam folder?

Comment: he's hitting his smtp server and it's rejecting the mail straight off because the from address is not a valid local address within the domain.